# For...Next Loop Multiplication Table to Start on 0

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, loops

I have my For...Next loop with a multiplication table working just fine, but I want the top left box to start at 0 and move on from there. Giving me some trouble.

```
dim mult

mult = "<table width = ""100%"" border= ""1"" >"

For row = 1 to 50

    mult = mult & "<tr align = ""center"" >"

    For col= 1 to 20

        mult = mult & "<td>" & row * col & "</td>"

    Next

    mult = mult & "</tr>"

Next

mult = mult & "</table>"

response.write mult
```

This is what I have so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this piece of code

`For row = 1 to 50`

for this one

`For row = 0 to 50`

Comment: That actually puts 0's across the top and bottom. I figure it out. 
dim mult
 mult = "<table width = ""100%"" border= ""1"" >"

 For row = 0 to 50

 mult = mult & "<tr align = ""center"" >"

 For col= 0 to 20

 if col = 0 then

   mult = mult & "<td>" & row& "</td>"

  else

  if row = 0 then

  mult = mult & "<td>" & col & "</td>"

  else

  mult = mult & "<td>" & row * col & "</td>"

  end if
    
  end if

  Next

  mult = mult & "</tr>"

  Next

 mult = mult & "</table>"

 response.write mult
Thank you though!

Comment: That actually puts 0's across the top and bottom. I figure it out. 

    For col= 0 to 20 

    if col = 0 

    then mult = mult & "<td>" & row& "</td>" 

    else if row = 0 

    then mult = mult & "<td>" & col & "</td>" 

    else mult = mult & "<td>" & row * col & "</td>"
 
    end if 

    end if 

     Next 

    mult = mult & "</tr>" 

Still getting used to how posting works

Answer (score 0):

Just change this piece of code

```
For row = 1 to 50
```

for this one

```
For row = 1 to 51
```

I think this will help you.